# Advice on closing orders that can not be viewed in a safe manner

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, database

In our order list, there are some which due to upgrading the payment
module can not be viewed and we are getting the error "The
requested Payment Method is not available". Considering that we already shipped the products regarding these orders, is it safe to delete them through sql query?  Or updating the order status in "sales_flat_order_grid" and "sales_flat_order"? what would be the best action?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest direct SQL queries. Instead, create a dummy payment method with the exact method code like before that doesn't do anything except giving some default values to Magento when viewing the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you don't use Magento for sales reporting, you can delete complete orders or change their payment method. You can update `sales_flat_order_payment` and change the invalid `method` values, as described here:
[In which table payment method information of order save](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94243/in-which-table-payment-method-information-of-order-save/97439#97439)

Answer (score 3):

The `sales_flat_order_grid` table only contains records that are visible on the grid. So if you remove any record from that table, the overall order storage will not be impacted and you'll not see this order on the grid. However this way there is no chance to get it back.
Some extensions exist that allow to archive orders. They basically work the following way: archived order information is being copied to another (new) table, and removed from original one. So you always have an option to restore.