# In which table payment method information of order save

Tags: orders, payment-methods

I am checking with admin panel order and suddenly when i view particular order. I get error

> Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'The requested Payment Method is not available.' .

It is inserted in database corrected or not i want to check this. How i can remove this error method. I want to know location of database table in which all information holds regarding magento order. And also when i print order by collection and used following line of code then same error is coming for that order.

```
$orders->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
```

Answer (score 12):

To find out which (nonexistent) payment method was used, have a look at the `sales_flat_order_payment` table which contains the payment information for each order (it has a 1:1 relation to `sales_flat_order` which is the main table for orders). You are looking for the `method` column.

To be able to load the orders again, you can change the invalid methods to a standard method like `checkmo`.

Answer (score 3):

Magento saves the *payment method settings as system configuration*, so you need to check their availability in the `core_config_data` table.

For your case, in the past, there was a payment method available at your system which is now disabled, or you have delete the payment module.

You can fix this by enabling this payment or if you deleted it, then you need to reinstall this payment method.

Comment: How to unset the payment method as null in quote, in magento 2